# Conditional Formating in Telerik Grid (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I want to change the cell background color based on a value.

My solution If ound and which worked was this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Models.Intern.CheckADGridModel>()
                .Name("ADGrid")
                .Filterable()
                .Sortable(s => s.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                .Pageable(page => page.Enabled(true))
                .Columns(col =>
                {
                    col.Bound(x => x.ProjectID).Filterable(true).Title("ID").Width(100);
                    col.Bound(x => x.ProjectName).Filterable(true).Title(ResourcesLocal.Resources_Intern_CheckAD.Name).ClientTemplate(
                    "<a href=\"" + @Url.Content("~/Home/Index/") +
                     "#= ProjectID #\"" +
                    "><span data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" title=\"" + @ResourcesLocal.Resources_Intern_CheckAD.ChooseProject + "\">" +
                     "#= ProjectName #" +
                     "</span ></a>");
                    col.Bound(x => x.StartDate).Filterable(false).Title(ResourcesLocal.Resources_Intern_CheckAD.Start).Width(150).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
                    col.Bound(x => x.EndDate).Filterable(false).Title(ResourcesLocal.Resources_Intern_CheckAD.Ende).Width(150).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
                    col.Bound(x => x.ConnectionLength).Filterable(true).Title(ResourcesLocal.Resources_Intern_CheckAD.Length).Width(70)
                        .ClientTemplate("#= formatADGridDauer(ConnectionLength) #");
            .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Sort(x => x.Add("EndDate").Descending())
                .Read(read => read.Action("DataSourceADGrid", "Intern").Data("GetADGridValues"))
                )
        )

function formatADGridDauer(value) {
            var css = "";
            if (parseFloat(value) >= 1800)
                css = "background-color:red; color:white;";
            else if (parseFloat(value) > 600)
                css = "background-color:Orange; color:white;";

            html = "<div style='" + css + "'>" + value + "</div>";
            html = kendo.format(html);
            return html;
        }
```

The problem is, I can only change the behaviour of the data in the cell, which means the padding of the grid-cell will be shown and it looks really ugly.

So how to do it right an change the gridcell background color instead of the data inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, telerik is not the most user-friendly set of controls when it comes to customization. Javascript (jquery in this instance) has worked for me when I had to do something similar.

**Try this something like this:**

```
$(".k-grid tr td").filter(function () { //gets the generated table cells
  if ($(this).text() > 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```